# "unknown function +()" error with catplot

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a graph using Stata but I am having a problem when I use catplot. I used the code of a graph that I previously made but now I cannot recreate it, everytime I try to use catplot the following error emerges:

```
(note:  pstyle p.bar not found in scheme, default attributes used)
unknown function +()
r(133);
```

I uninstalled and installed it again but this problem still happens. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Here is a code to recreate the issue:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. catplot rep78 foreign, percent(rep78) asyvars stack 
(note:  pstyle p.bar not found in scheme, default attributes used)
(note:  pstyle p.bar not found in scheme, default attributes used)
(note:  pstyle p.bar not found in scheme, default attributes used)
(note:  pstyle p.bar not found in scheme, default attributes used)
(note:  pstyle p.bar not found in scheme, default attributes used)
unknown function +()
r(133);

end of do-file
```

Comment: Your example works on my computer. It could be that catplot depends on the installation of other user-written commands, or the problem might stem from the graph scheme you are using. If you are using a different one, try  to set the default scheme with `set scheme s2color` (or another one, see `help set scheme`) before plotting your graph.

Comment: Using `catplot` doesn't depend on installing anything else. My diagnosis is quite different. Your Stata installation is corrupt or incomplete. I'd reinstall the purchased copy or else contact Stata Technical Services (together with your licensing information).

Comment: Thank you! I restarted my computer after I posted this and now it works perfectly, so I am not sure what was the problem